Dividing huggingface model between 2 kaggle 15 gb gpus
I am now trying to download llama from hugging face using kaggel notebook, it is downloaded in the 16 GB gpu. Is there any way such that I can download the model in the two 15 gpus in kaggle also, but I want to divide the model between them, which means I want , let's say, 8 gb in the first gpu, and the rest in the other gpu.
I know that I can use accelerate from hugging face to do that, but I tried alot and each time, the model is ducplicated in the two gpus not divided.
